# CSS sliding underline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have horizontal menu on my website. I want the menu links to smoothly underline.
HTML

```
<nav id="nav_container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Sportovci</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Specialisté</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Kluby</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Obchody</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Ligy</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Články</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav_item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav_item:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.nav_item:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #236fe8;
}
```

With this code the link will underline from left to right on hover, but when i go out with mouse it doesn't smoothly go back. I think it will be some JavaScript (jQuery), but don't know how.
I also want the clicked (active) link to stay underlined. How to do this?

I will be thankful for every kind of answer.

Comment: Looks ok to me ? http://jsfiddle.net/fX6xz/ Also tested in, Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: yes, looks ok to me too..

Comment: Maybe you want to add an `#nav_container a { text-decoration: none; }` to make your effect more visible.

Comment: make sure you add browser prefixes, -moz-transition, etc.

Comment: FYI: doesn't work with my IE10

Comment: Does work with IE11, although the lines seem to be closer to each other than in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about targeting the anchors instead of the `.nav_item`s like so:

```
a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #236fe8;
}
```

Here your [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX6xz/5/).

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this one

```
.nav_item:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0;`enter code here`
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .9s ease;
}
```

go to the following link for more help, i hope it will resolve your problem
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp